# rgvdslam v2 roslaunch error in ubuntu 14.04 ros indigo

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I try "roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch" I got error

REQUIRED process [rgbdslam-23] has died! process has died [pid 7397, exit code -11, cmd /home/slam/rgbdslam_catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbdslam/rgbdslam __name:=rgbdslam __log:=/home/slam/.ros/log/86f0937e-3be5-11e5-8018-c86000307f44/rgbdslam-23.log]. log file: /home/slam/.ros/log/86f0937e-3be5-11e5-8018-c86000307f44/rgbdslam-23*.log Initiating shutdown!

if someone has seen or solved it, could u help me? how to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215324/rgvdslam-v2-roslaunch-error-in-ubuntu-14.04-ros-indigo/) by [rgbdQuestion](https://answers.ros.org/users/23473/rgbdquestion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dinl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23729/dinl/) on 2015-12-16**:
did you solve it?

**Comment by [Mr. Kro](https://answers.ros.org/users/26652/mr.-kro/) on 2016-05-12**:
Had the same problem, and no, re-compiling PCL with C++11 and `catkin_make` again with new PCL didn't solve it.

**Comment by [Dox](https://answers.ros.org/users/34329/dox/) on 2018-04-03**:
Has anyone managed to solve this problem at the end? I tried following [this](https://hubpages.com/technology/Instructions-for-compiling-rgbdslam-v2-on-a-fresh-Ubuntu-1604-install-ros-kinetic-in-virtualbox) but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Download the newest version of RGBDSLAM from https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2  for indigo.
Now it works well.

---

Originally posted by [Gloria@HK](https://answers.ros.org/users/14486/gloria@hk/) with karma: 26 on 2016-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem but this is an old and known issue: https://github.com/felixendres/rgbdslam_v2/issues/8

You need to compile the PCL with C++11 and link rgbdslam with it.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-07-06**:
Are you using kinect2? If you use kinect2, you should install libfreenect2 and iai_kinect2. And you should change topic of data sequence from kinect2 in rgbdslam.launch